# java blob to byte array conversion error issue

Tags: java, blob

I am getting error in converting. We are using hibernate here.
Please suggest how we can resolve the issue..

```
blob = (Blob) resultList.get(i);
int blobLength = (int) blob.length();
topublishedFile = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
```

The error which we are getting is as follows.

```
2014-04-15 15:34:54,880 INFO  DB2Interceptor.onPrepareStatement - IN INTERCEPTOR CLASS
[4/15/14 15:34:54:881 IST] 00000025 SystemOut     O Hibernate: select STD_BLOB_PDF FROM estd.tbadress where std_number = ? with ur for fetch only 
[4/15/14 15:39:47:515 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: [jcc][10120][11936][3.50.152] Invalid operation: Lob is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null
[4/15/14 15:39:47:515 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wc.a(wc.java:55)
[4/15/14 15:39:47:515 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wc.a(wc.java:93)
[4/15/14 15:39:47:515 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.rd.d(rd.java:67)
[4/15/14 15:39:47:515 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.rd.r(rd.java:56)
[4/15/14 15:39:47:515 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.rd.length(rd.java:41)
```

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014269660

Comment: Invalid operation: Lob is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Comment: wnt through the site but still no resolution

Comment: have you tried:  $ db2set DB2_RESTRICT_DDF=true as my attachment was not working .. After setting this parameter, its working fine.